# Would the size or number of installed packages affect server performance

Tags: node.js

As I'm learning, I'm seeing many developers use a large variety of packages in an app. I'm sure much of the functionality of these packages aren't needed in the app.

Would too many packages slow server performance in a similar way that multiple javascript libraries would on the client side? Is this a smaller or non-issue since the packages aren't being downloaded on each new visit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because a module is installed on the file system in node_modules doesn't mean that any of the code from the entry point of your application actually require/imports it.

The modules get loaded in as they are imported, which is usually pretty much all of them at the beginning, although you can make some modules load dynamically in only certain circumstances if you want.

No, of course the packages aren't being reloaded on each request.  The Node server stays running until it crashes or you stop it.  Each request is handled by the same running server, with the same set of modules already loaded unless a request causes it to load a new module, which is unusual.  What would affect the performance of the server would usually not be the amount of modules or size on disk, but the actual activities that those modules are performing.  For many applications, most of the modules do nothing until they are used while serving a request, so having 100 modules loaded into memory or 10, they are still doing nothing if there is no request.

More modules will use more memory at runtime.  If you have many loaded, this could theoretically use up the memory on a very small server, which would kill the performance.  But it would have to be a server with very little resources.

If you create an application where even 1 module is busy doing some CPU intensive processing, or 1 module is doing a synchronous IO task, or one module is thrashing memory by causing lots of garbage collection, then that will block the application from processing requests efficiently since its single threaded.  But this is an issue you will have if you have even one module misbehaving like that, and isn't about having lots of modules being used/loaded by your application.  The vast majority of modules provide small bits of functionality that isn't synchronous or CPU-intensive, so having lots of them doesn't really increase your chances of having a misbehaving module.

It can take a few minutes to *install* lots of dependency modules, however.  But this usually isn't a problem if you use newer versions of npm and stay away from underpowered servers like AWS's 'free' tiny EC2 instances.